# Which geoip database is used for which app?

Tags: package-management, geolocation

This question is a bit generic.  I find a number of geoip databases and references on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.  At /usr/share/geoip and /usr/share/GeoIP and also at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/geoip and again for Tor at /usr/share/tor/geoip .  My question is how do I know which geoip I'm employing when I'm working with geospatial website analysis?  Also, how are these updated and when (especially IPv6 addresses) and by what mechanism?  Do they all enable IPv6?

Comment: You've have to be more specific than you are, but I'm thinking of on *app* in particularly (*and only one app*) and we've adjusted it when errors have been noticed in QA or bug reports filed, we investigate & rather commonly too, the API we use now has restrictions thus we change which site we use for the *development* release & SRU for prior *supported* releases. In this case I'm thinking only of a specific app supported by a *two* Ubuntu teams. Ubuntu does provide their own (*which we use for some releases*) but your answer can be package specific as I'm trying to show.